# Delete some part of filenames from a folder using index with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, directory, filenames

I have been studying PHP. and I came across a thought if there is a way to delete just some part of the file names using the filename's index.

```
For example, if the files are named as 

    abcdefghijk.jpg
    lmnopqrstuv.jpg
```

and Lets say we want to delete from 6th character until 11th character, which means from "f" until "k" in 1st and "q" until "v" in 2nd.

```
and the output should be

abcde.jpg
lmnop.jpg
```

Comment: You can use unlink() funtion.

Comment: You mean _rename_?

Comment: @NowshadRuhaniChowdhury Doesn't sound like OP wants to delete the file, just rename it

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to rename. 
rename("images","pictures");
rename("/test/file1.txt","/home/docs/my_file.txt");

check this.

Comment: Rename function use this: rename(old, new, context)

Comment: yes, sorry if i wasn't clear. i meant to rename them. but only some part of it should change but the remaining stays as same as i explained above.   @NowshadRuhaniChowdhury

Comment: yes, sorry if i wasn't clear. i meant to rename them. but only some part of it should change but the remaining stays as same as i explained above. @ChrisHaas

Comment: Did you mean that abcdefghijk.jpg to rename it  abcde.jpg?

Comment: `rename` is pretty straight forward, so now we're just changing a string. PHP has a bunch of [string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), and I think [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is what you are looking for, possibly along with [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to deal with file extensions.